# Single characters are not printed on the terminal

Tags: c, printf

I have 3 different processes that all print out single characters using `printf`. But I can't see them in the terminal. When I add a newline, `printf("\n H")` so each character is on a new line, I can see them. Why doesn't it work without the newline character?

Comment: Please post the code that is not working.

Comment: Can you post some code that you are facing problem with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a matter of flushing. If you flush the buffers after each `printf`, you should get output closer to what you want. To flush the standard output simply do `fflush( stdout )`.

Comment: Also, output is usually buffered until a newline or a certain amount of data in the buffer is reached. That's why you didn't need to flush when using a newline.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard defines 3 types of buffering for output streams:

- Unbuffered → no buffering done
- Line-buffered → buffer until newline seen
- Fully-bufferd → buffer up to the buffer size

An output stream's buffering type can be changed via the `setvbuf(3)` and `setbuf(3)` functions.

The C standard requires `stderr` to not be fully-buffered at startup (it is usually unbuffered on many implementations, so as to see errors as soon as posible); and `stdout` to be fully-buffered only if it can be determined to not refer to a terminal (when it refers to a terminal, many implementations initialize it as line-buffered, which is what you are seeing).

Answer (score -1):

use'write(1,&c,1)' system call, or

```
fprintf(stderr,'%c', c);
```

Comment: `stderr` usually points to `stdout` and is flushed after every write, however it could be piped to point to any other file (different that the one `stdout` points to) so this is not a valid solution.